# json_decode in php, index 0 being ignore

Tags: php, json

I've faced a very very weird problem, which I unable to solve for 2 days.

```
while ($rs_sub = $resultSub->fetchRow()) {
$i=0;
$new = json_decode($rs_sub['content'],1);
foreach ($new as $value) {
    if (!(empty($value['type'])) && !($value['type'] == 'captcha') && !($value['label'] == 'files') && !($value['type'] == 'hidden') && !($value['label'] == 'divider')) {
        if (($value['type'] == 'radio' || $value['type'] == 'check' || $value['type'] == 'matrix' || $value['type'] == 'stars' || $value['type'] == 'smiley' || $value['type'] == "thumbs") && $value['value']!="") {
            if (!in_array($value['label'], $label)) {
                $label[] = $value['label'];
            }
            if ($value['type'] == "thumbs") {
                if($value['value']=="1"){
                    $value['value']="Like";
                }else{
                    $value['value']="Dislike";
                }
            }
            if (!in_array($value['value'], $choice[$value['label']])) {
                    $choice[$value['label']][] = $value['value'];
            }
            $var=array_search($value[value], $choice[$value['label']]);
            if (array_search($value['value'], $choice[$value['label']])) {
                echo $var;
                $ans[$value['label']][$var] = $ans[$value['label']][$var] + 1;
            } else {
                $ans[$value['label']][$var] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Here is the output.

```
11111111111122331331331331331331331331331343413413413413413413413411211211212412431131421311
```

It should be

```
00011111111111102020033133133133133133133133133134034134134134134134134134112112112124000012431013014201030100001
```

All the 0 are being ignored inside the if conditions, I have no idea why this is happening.
I've tried (string), strval() and many other but nothing work.

Note: $rs_sub['content'] is a field in my db.

**EDIT**:
If I put "echo $var" outside the if else condition, it will work (0 is being echo out).

**EDIT 2**
This is my json code in db

```
{"1":{"label":"pkid","value":"undefined","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"3":{"label":"","value":"","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"4":{"label":"Service","value":"4","type":"stars","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field0","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"5":{"label":"Service-Reason","value":"","type":"stars","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field0","custom":"reason","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"6":{"label":"Food","value":"5","type":"smiley","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field1","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"7":{"label":"Food-Reason","value":"","type":"smiley","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field1","custom":"reason","custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"8":{"label":"Like it?","value":"1","type":"thumbs","validation":"","required":"0","min":"","max":"","tooltip":"field2","custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"9":{"label":"pkid","value":"1913","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"10":{"label":"title","value":"Form Title","type":null,"validation":null,"required":null,"min":null,"max":null,"tooltip":null,"custom":null,"custom2":null,"custom3":"zz","custom4":null},"0":{"custom3":"zz","label":"","value":null},"2":{"custom3":"zz","label":"","value":null}}
```

Comment: what you try to achieve?

Comment: Show the content of `$choice` too. And `$value[value]` is not correct (except if you defined a constant named `value`). It should be `$value['value']`. PHP issues a notice for that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious: the `if` condition is `if ($var)`. When `$var == 0` the condition evaluates to `FALSE` and it runs the `else` branch of the `if`. But there is no `echo` on the else branch.